# How to enable apache rewrites step by step

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am writing scripts for Apache URL redirects.

I have researched the rewrite rules to be written.

Now I would like to know the procedure for implementing this.

1. Enabling mod_rewrites in http.conf

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so 
   AddModule mod_rewrite.c
   ```
2. I have created .htaccess

Now I am not sure of the following.

```
 1.Access rights required to do this. 

 2.The location to put .htaccess file 

 3.how to enable logs and write logs.

 4.I have two web servers.Do I have to put this in both of them.
```

My rewrite rule looks some thing like this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old_domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.com/test$1 [L,R=301]
```

It would be good if some one help me with the step by step procedure to perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Access rights required to do this.

You need write access to the folder the htaccess file is going to be uploaded to, and the htaccess file itself must have read rights by the webserver (most likely, the "apache" user)

Additionally, you need to have at the very least:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

in the server config for the document root directory

> 2.The location to put .htaccess file

Based on the rules you have, you want it in the document root. It's denoted in the server config by the `DocumentRoot` directive

> 3.how to enable logs and write logs.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Specifically the `TransferLog` and `ErrorLog` directives

> 4.I have two web servers.Do I have to put this in both of them.

Do the same thing for each. If both webservers use the same document root, then obviously you don't need to put the htaccess file in 2 places. If they have different document roots, then put the htaccess file in both document roots.